# python: read from .txt and judge the new string in the txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read/write txt file. I want to read from txt file, and then write new string to the next line if the string not existed in the original file.

```
f = open('./video/1.txt', 'a')
f.write('123' + '\n')
f.close()

with open('./video/1.txt') as o:
    lines=o.readlines()

lines=set(lines)

if '123' in lines:
    print("Existed")
else:print("Not Existed")
```

The question is : i have '123' is the 1.txt file. And the result is "Not Existed" And I tried to use

```
for line in lines:
    print(line + '\n')
```

to print out the set variable "lines", it print out 123 at one line. I am confused now. What causes the "NOT EXISTED"? Thank you.

Update: I uploaded the screenshot. Still confused.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is checking if an element of the `set` `lines` is '`123`'

example:

```
lines = ['hello there', 'hello 123 there', '123']
if '123' in lines:
    print("Existed")
else:print("Not Existed")
```

output:

```
Existed
```

example:

```
lines = ['hello there', 'hello 123 there']
if '123' in lines:
    print("Existed")
else:print("Not Existed")
```

output:

```
Not Existed
```

You could do something like this:

```
lines = ['hello there', 'hello 123 there']
for line in lines:
    if '123' in line:
        print('Existed')
```

If you are reading from file, you could be getting a trailing carriage-return character in you line, this is `\n`. This could also cause your `if '123' in lines` to go wrong, even when the line is only '`123`', reality is the line is actually '`123\n`'.

example:

```
ms = '123\n'
print(ms)
mb = ms.encode()
print(mb)
```

output:

```
123

b'123\n'
```

in this sample output, as well as in your screenshot, you can actually see the extra carriage return in the output. Hence your string is not '`123`' your string is '`123\n`'

Comment: I just updated the question, Sorry for the misunderstanding. I hope now it is clearly.

Comment: Yeah. I upload the screenshot. I am not sure if it is clear now.

Comment: @XiChen Do not forget to check mark with give vote point for Edwin effort man

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Edwin van Mierlo 's answer, i got this now. 
This is a '\n' after 123. So if i use '123\n' instead of 123, it shows existed.

```
if '123\n' in lines:
    print("Existed")
else:print("Not Existed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but anyway

Instead of keep using `lines` as a variable I will use `lines1`

```
In [3]: with open('1.txt') as o:
   ...:     lines = o.readlines()
   ...:

In [4]: lines1 = set(lines)
```

If you do a print on `lines1`, this is the result you have.

```
In [5]: print(lines1)
{'123\n'}
```

Where does this take you?

One possible solution is to use a regex to look for `123` in your set, if you wish to continue with your set.

The regex `\d+` will look for digit.

```
In [6]: import re

In [7]: if re.search(r'\d+', str(lines1)):
   ...:     print('yes')
   ...: else:
   ...:     print('no')
   ...:
yes
```